# Ubuntu 18.04 auto logout even when do some task

Tags: gnome, system

i have problems about my Ubuntu 18.04 is auto logout even when do some task, just like when I'm browsing on internet, and Ubuntu logout it self with no error. And of course i should run the application again because it closed when logout

this is very annoying, can anyone help please ?

Thank You

Comment: The "auto logout" *is the error*. It's a desktop crash. Note the exact time of a crash. Check /var/log/syslog for the logged events leading to the crash. Check /var/crash for the the (usually) complete record of the crash. Together, they will tell you what happened, and often provide a clue to the trigger.